# CGLGetDeviceFromGLRenderer alternative on 10.9

Tags: macos, opengl, core-graphics, opencl, gpgpu

On a Mac Pro, I need to find the cl_device_id of the GPU that is connected to the screen.

CGLGetDeviceFromGLRenderer is mentioned (in WWDC 2014, Session 601) as the API for translating the virtual screen number of an OpenGL renderer to the equivalent OpenCL device id.

The problem is that CGLGetDeviceFromGLRenderer is available only on OS X 10 (Yosemite).

Is there an alternative or a workaround for Mac OS 10.9?

Comment: The CL device that is able to get a CL/GL interop context is usually the one connected to the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the function by yourself:

```
#if !defined(MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_10)
cl_device_id CGLGetDeviceFromGLRenderer(GLint rendererID)
{
    // For GPUs that support OpenCL in Mac OS X, the rendererID may be
    // transformed into a cl_device_id by masking away the low byte:
    // https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2335/_index.html
    cl_device_id device_id = (cl_device_id)(intptr_t)(rendererID &~ 0xff);
    return device_id;
}
#endif
```